# R: Sum the Max Values of Unique Rows with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to come up with a sum for each task in a dataset that only uses the largest value observed for the id once in the sum. If that's not clear I've provided an example of the desired output below.

**Sample Data**

```
dat <- data.frame(task = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=3), 
                  id = c(rep(1:2, 4) , 3),
                  value = c(rep(c(10,20), 4), 5))
dat
  task id value
1    A  1    10
2    A  2    20
3    A  1    10
4    B  2    20
5    B  1    10
6    B  2    20
7    C  1    10
8    C  2    20
9    C  3     5
```

I've found an answer that works, but it requires two separate `group_by()` functions. Is there a way to get the same output with a single `group_by()`? The reason is I have other summarized metrics that are sensitive to the grouping and I can't run two different `group_by` functions in the same pipeline.

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(task, id) %>%
  summarize(v = max(value)) %>%
  group_by(task) %>%
  summarize(unique_ids = n_distinct(id), 
            value_sum = sum(v))

# A tibble: 3 × 3
   task unique_ids value_sum
  <chr>      <int>     <dbl>
1     A          2        30
2     B          2        30
3     C          3        35
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found something that works using `tapply()`.

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(task) %>%
  summarize(unique_ids = length(unique(id)), 
            value_sum = sum(tapply(value, id, FUN = max)))

# A tibble: 3 × 3
   task unique_ids value_sum
  <chr>      <int>     <dbl>
1     A          2        30
2     B          2        30
3     C          3        35
```

Comment: Fyi, for length(unique(x)) there's n_distinct in dplyr. I think this can be solved by dropping duplicates: `dat %>% distinct %>% group_by(task) %>% summarise(n = n(), s = sum(value))`. To the extent that other metrics get in the way of that, I think that comes from the decision to use one table when really you should have multiple (e.g., one for `id`s and their attributes). You might want to read Hadley's paper on "tidy data"

Comment: Thanks for tip on `n_distinct`. I can't drop duplicate rows because I have other columns I need to summarize that are dependent on all rows being retained.

Comment: Shouldn't be the result of tapply be converted to numeric for summing? Such as: `dat %>% 
  group_by(task) %>%
  summarize(unique_ids = length(unique(id)), 
            value_sum = sum(as.numeric(tapply(value, id, FUN = max))))`